# Resin is showing my app as active but I am getting 404

Tags: java, deployment, resin, caucho

as In topic my war is running without errors on Jetty / Tomcat but when I deploy it to the Resin 4
It shows as running / active in the deployed applications tab on the resin-admin panel. Nothing unusual in the logs as well. 
But when I try to access myapp I am getting 404

```
    Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.server.cluster.Server start
INFO: resin.conf = null
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.server.cluster.Server start
INFO: 
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.lifecycle.Lifecycle toActive
INFO: Host[] active
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.server.port.Port bind
INFO: http listening to *:8080
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.lifecycle.Lifecycle toActive
INFO: Server[id=,cluster=] active
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.server.resin.Resin start
INFO: Resin started in 2804ms
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.lifecycle.Lifecycle toStopping
INFO: Host[] stopping
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:25 AM com.caucho.lifecycle.Lifecycle toActive
INFO: Host[] active
Aug 14, 2013 9:20:26 AM com.caucho.lifecycle.Lifecycle toActive
INFO: WebApp[http://localhost:8080/myapp] active
```

web 3.0 app initializer

```
import com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

@Order(1)
public class AppWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new SiteMeshFilter() };
    }
```

Comment: Is it a servlet application? then please show us the web.xml

Comment: it is servlet 3.0 with @ and no web.xml

Comment: how does the annotation looks like?

Comment: I have added Initializer class

Comment: did you try it with http://localhost:8080/myapp/ ?

Comment: yes I did and it gives me 404 ...

Comment: sorry I mean with "/" at the end.

Comment: everything gives me 404 and no errors in the resin log... localhost:8080/myapp; localhost:8080/myapp/; localhost:8080/myapp//;